# what is the meaning of IntelliJ android-validator error?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Does someone know what this message means ?
 Cannot build release Android artifacts in the 'make before run' session Release artifacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the same error. All I had to do was go into my manifest and remove the minSDK requirement I had of 4. For some reason that took care of the bug. Did you find another solution?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error.

In my project settings artifact dialog I had chosen "Build on Make". In the run dialog I had chosen "Deploy custom artifact."

To fix the error, in the project settings artifacts dialog, I unselected "Build on Make." but in the run dialog I made sure that it still says "Deploy custom artifact". But at the bottom of the run dialog, make sure that it says there "Build your_artifact_name artifact."

Then it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, after changing project SDK to another android version. I fix this by remove "make" before launch and create unsigned artifact that is deploy on android emulator

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by implementing something similar to user2934013's answer, but I'm going to try to explain in more detail:

My problem was that I was trying to run unit tests and I was seeing this "make before run" error.  Removing the minSDK is not possible for me because I depend on backwards compatibility.  I only started seeing the issue after upgrading to Intellij 13.

The cause seemed to be that I had set up an Artifact for my android project and checked "Build on Make".  For some reason this was conflicting when running the unit tests (but not a regular build for emulator or device).  I unchecked that box in the artifact settings and the problem went away.

There is probably a way to fix the build order so this works correctly but I am not familiar enough with setting up a custom Artifact build to know how to do this.